# Number of solutions to equation of varying size, with varying upper-bound range restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Given:

$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = k$

where each $x_i$ can have some value between $0$ and $10$ (we might have $0\leq x_1\leq 7$ and we might have $0\leq x_2\leq 9$ and so on...)

How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to an equation like this, where each $x_i$ can take on any of the values in its range restrictions?

Is Mick A's answer applicable to this from the following? [Number of solutions to equation, range restrictions per variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049431/number-of-solutions-to-equation-range-restrictions-per-variable?rq=1)

If so, how would Mick A's answer be extended for equations of arbitrary lengths of the left-hand side? How could this be solved for programmatically?

EDIT: My thoughts are that we calculate $S$ and then subtract $S_1, S_2, ..., S_n$ from it, after which we add all intersections $S_1 \cap S_2, ...$ and then we subtract all "three-way intersections" $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3, ... $ and then we add all the "four-way intersections" $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4,...$ and then we subtract all the "five-way intersections" etc...

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: The method described in your thoughts is correct. It is written up in more detail in [the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded). However, in the worst case, this requires a sum over $2^n$ possible multi-way intersections, so whether this counts as a valid programmatical solution depends on how big $n$ is. If you use the generating function method, this may be faster depending on the $n,k$ and the upper limits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mike. Do you have any resources or other answers to refer to, where the generating function method is implemented, for this particular problem?

Comment: The algorithm in the approach to my answer will involve $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} = 2^k$ terms, each of which will either equal $0$, or have form $\binom{a}{b}$.  There is a programmatic shortcut.  Suppose that you have a binary counter that loops through $0$ through $[(2^k) - 1].$  Zero filled, this counter will loop through all of the $2^k$ possible binary strings of $1$'s and $0$'s.  Reading (for example) right to left, you can have digit $i$ having the value $1$ rather than $0$ signify that the upper bound constraint on variable $x_i$ is violated. ...see next comment

Comment: You can then programmatically evaluate the specific term that corresponds to anyone of the $2^k$ binary numbers.  Further, rather than attempting a $T_0, T_1, \cdots, T_k$ partition of the terms you can have the sign of the term be $(+1)$ rather than $(-1)$ if and only if the number of $1$'s in the corresponding binary string is even rather than odd.  Further, you will notice that those terms that evaluate as positive, rather than $0$ will all have form $\binom{a}{k-1}$.  ...see next comment

Comment: This means that you can have a preliminary step in your program where you evaluate all values $\binom{a}{k-1}$, where $(k-1) \leq a \leq [n + (k-1)]$.  I know that Java (for example) provides a BigInteger class for *integer only* computations.  Presumably, a similar facility is available for such programming languages as C or Python.  The only challenge here, is if you have to calculate something like $\binom{100}{20}$.  Personally, I would advise using the algorithm $$\frac{100 \times 99 \times \cdots \times 81}{20 \times 19 \times \cdots \times 1}$$ for such an expression.

Comment: Re end of last comment, given that such an expression always evaluates to an integer, depending on how large $n,k$ are, you might consider *programmatic cancellation* during the evaluation.  For example $\frac{100}{20} \to \frac{5}{1},~$ while $\frac{92}{8} \to \frac{23}{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let upper bound of $x_1,x_2..,x_n$ be given as $i_n$, then the answer is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the product:

$$ S= \prod_{j=1}^n (1 + x+x^2...+x^{i_1})$$

Now, suppose one was doing the problem by hand , then we can use a trick to reduce the calculations required in the above step. Consider the product,

$$ S'= \prod_{j=1}^n( \frac{1}{1-x} -\sum_{p=i_1+1}^k x^p)$$

It can be observed that in the above, the coefficient of $x^k$ is that of the one in $S$. The above form is also easier to compute. For instance, consider this problem:

> Number of ways we can draw 6 chocolates drawn from 15 chocolates out of which 4 are blue, 5 are red and 6 are green if chocolates of the same colour are not distinguishable?

We are looking for solution of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15$ with $0 \leq x_1 \leq 4$, $0 \leq  x_2 \leq 5$ , $0 \leq x_3 \leq 6$. We have,

$$ S'=  (\frac{1}{1-x} -x^5 -x^6)( \frac{1}{1-x} -x^6 ) ( \frac{1}{1-x} )= (\frac{1}{1-x} -x^5 -x^6)\left[\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{x^6}{(1-x) }\right] \equiv \frac{1}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{x^6}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{x^5}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{x^6}{(1-x)^2}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{2x^6}{(1-x)^2}  - \frac{x^5}{(1-x)^2} $$

The above is quite easily calculable.

Comment: More details on the idea of dropping and inserting terms hwich preserve coefficients [here](https://boringmathmusings.blogspot.com/2020/07/the-beauty-of-infinite-geometric-series.html)

Comment: This is super inefficient. When $n=3$ and $(i_1,i_2,i_3)=(3,6,10)$, and $k=13$, your method requires expanding
$$
\left(\frac1{1-x}-x^4-\dots-x^{13}\right)\left(\frac1{1-x}-x^7-\dots-x^{13}\right)\left(\frac1{1-x}-x^{11}-x^{12}-x^{13}\right)
$$
which has way to many terms. The same problem instance would be doable by hand if you used the generating function method [described in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/554237).