# How many unique combinations can I make with 18 elements (2a, 2b, 2c, 3d, 4e, 5f) that I distribute into 6 groups of 3?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 18 elements `(2a, 2b, 2c, 3d, 4e, 5f)` that I need to distribute into 6 unordered groups of 3.
I want to now the number of unique combinations I can make with those rules.

I read various website but as of now I only find way to measure the combination of 18 *different* elements into 6 group of 3

$$x=(18!/15!)\times(15!/12!)\times(12!/9!)\times(9!/6!)\times(6!/3!)\times(3!/1!)$$

(or in Excel format)

```
=(FACT(18)/FACT(15))*(FACT(15)/FACT(12))*(FACT(12)/FACT(9))*(FACT(9)/FACT(6))*(FACT(6)/FACT(3))*(FACT(3)/FACT(1))
```

And I’m not even sure of what I did :D

Thanks a lot for your help

--- progress  ---

Following @Bulbasaur link advices, the Mathematical formula should be

$$
F_{\text{group1}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=2}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
F_{\text{group2}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=2}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
F_{\text{group3}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=2}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
F_{\text{group4}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=3}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
F_{\text{group5}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=4}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
F_{\text{group6}}(u,v,w,x,y,z)=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,l,m,n \,\ge \,0,\\ i+j+k+l+m+n=5}} u^iv^jw^kx^ly^mz^n
$$

$$
\text{# ways}=[u^3v^3w^3x^3y^3z^3](F_{\text{group1}}\times F_{\text{group2}}\times F_{\text{group3}}\times F_{\text{group4}}\times F_{\text{group5}}\times F_{\text{group6}})
$$

I now have two questions:
first, is this formula correct (and efficient)?
Second, how do I calculate it? (I’m a designer so I usually do this kind of thing in Excel :D )

Thanks for you help

Comment: You could try your method on some smaller cases (with fewer different types) which can be worked out by hand.

Comment: This *[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302624/distributing-10-indistinguishable-cars-12-indistinguishable-balls-14-ind)* is answering your question , you just need to turn this into indistinguishable  dividing the result by $6!$ .Moreover , please use *[matjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)*. Also , show what you tried to solve your question

Comment: Thanks for answering. However I do not understand how to do what’s in the answer you linked on Excel (which is the only tool I know to calculate this)

Just for context: I’m a designer, so my last Math teaches were 10 years ago. I’ve spend my afternoon yesterday to find the formula above…

Comment: Your question seems to be a particular case of this more general question: [Partitioning a multiset into multisets of fixed sizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856255/partitioning-a-multiset-into-multisets-of-fixed-sizes)

Comment: Another way to formulate the problem is this: You want to count the number of matrices with 6 rows of 6 columns of nonnegative integer coefficients, such that each row sums to 3 (each row corresponds to one group) and the columns sum to 2,2,2,3,4,5 respectively (each column corresponds to one letter).

Comment: Can you clarify, DomitienAW, does the order of the groups matter? For example, do you want to count the partition {A, A, B} , {B, C, C}, {D, D, D}, {E, E, E}, {E, F, F}, {F, F, F} as different from  {B, C, C}, {A, A, B} , {D, D, D}, {E, E, E}, {E, F, F}, {F, F, F}, or are these the same?

Comment: @MikeEarnest the order of the group doesn’t matter

Comment: thanks @Bulbasaur, I’ve updated my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** There are $15{,}628$ ways to distribute the objects into groups.

Your problem is equivalent to counting the number of $6\times 6$ matrices whose rows all sum to $3$, and whose column sums are $\{2,2,2,3,4,5\}$, **except** that matrices are considered equivalent when they differ by a permutation of rows.

Without the row-permutation condition, you can use [method 2 in my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4302713) to find the number of matrices. In order to account for row permutations, you can use Burnside's lemma, averaging over $S_6$ the number of matrices which are fixed by each permutation. It turns out you can count the fixed points for a permutation with a similar generating function.

This is all too complicated to be done without a computer algebra system. Here is my Mathematica program which gives the answer at the beginning: [Mathematica computation of number of matrices up to row permutation.](https://tio.run/##bVJha9swEP3uX3GjMOzikSVO8mFlECikMNYRFn9IEFrRXDVVZ8tDlrca49@e3l28uMkKEta99/Tu9HCh/KMulDeZ2u838Bna53EMzxPcCe4p7hnueXcVbIltkG2QbZBtkG2QbYgN1kQjc1hIIztDIiU8YWRYdOG3cnPiAgBo0fZkdTHDk7exyRvApK@Sc31y0A9V0h@nJ7LpYDEb0HlHHxpXuV0l/ihX3cXgqbiT8AnHJ0iICylj@NgzXHbwHkYL@K7sTgvs81XbnX9kBymD4Ftd3CrvTKYrsUbLFHeuip/sGsBteV/nWnA4W6v/YlCp@qXF9mhEYmxKgvSVID0T8PikulmiZOXQN/OCUBiPwjF8gI0QRsofJBfiSUrY8ieKoTWcUO@3kR1CTwzx/ZNGnbxCcK2d0dV1qR8eTGa09bBYwJfSWNHeLPE6p7OJYS37M70t5gfwqBhMUee@Esco4Lqsrec6hgt5FuoqrytqwSNwqCvtCvF/kOjdWgrg1QXO7l7bskAiTE2hj1R0OdRLlfnSGZVT52E6GXGsR1ZYOWKzwzNWzuDY/9qFYT8aedCPH8ElhCf/AKYwPJAl0Wj@Tgb7/Qs)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpfull answer !