# Stars and Bars But With A Unique Upper Limit For Each

Tags: combinatorics

This question has been asked before on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded):

We can know the number of solutions such that $a_1+a_2+a_3+....a_n=N$, $a_i\geq0$, and $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ can be found by stars and bars ($\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}$). But if we (like the question linked) wanted to then add the requirement that each $a_i\leq r_i$ and that $r_i$ can be unique for each $i$ how many combinations are there?

I've been trying to understand Mike Earnest's answer as theirs seemed more understandable but have come short on the last equation:
$$\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{|S|}\binom{N+n-1-\sum_{i\in S}(r_i+1)}{n-1}$$
From my understanding, it seems that the larger summation is used to subtract $x$ number of combinations from the total amount, but that seems to be contradictory with $(-1)^{|S|}$ since it would change from adding or subtracting based on if $S$ is even or odd? I also was wondering if there was any reason it was total value and not just $S$?

I also think I understand how we get ${\sum_{i\in S}(r_i+1)}$ since it's the same as the equation done before but it seems to mess up the equation since it often produces a negative factorial integer which can't be solved. I know to define $\binom{m}k=0$ when $m < 0$ but don't seem to get an accurate answer with these 2 questions lingering.

If we take the example that is given in the past post that $N = 6, n = 3$, and $(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(3,3,2)$ then our answer should be 5 since the only possibilities are (1,3,2), (2,2,2), (3,2,1), (3,1,2), and (2,3,1) but if we calculate it, it would be:$$\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}-\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,2,3\}}(-1)^{|S|}\binom{6+3-1-\sum_{i\in S}(r_i+1)}{3-1}$$ $$\binom{8}{2}-((-1)^{|1|}\binom{8-(3+3+2)}{2}+(-1)^{|2|}\binom{8-(3+3+2)}{2}+(-1)^{|3|}\binom{8-(3+3+2)}{2})$$
I wasn't sure what $i\in S$ meant when used in a summation, so I assumed it was the summation of all the numbers 1-3 in case that was where I went wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: See the answer given to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range).

Comment: Re: your comments on the "negative factorial": if the factorial definition of $\binom{n}k$ does not work, you should instead interpret $\binom nk$ as _the number of subsets of an $n$-element set with size $k$_. For example, $\binom{6}{-2}=0$, since none (0) of the subsets of a six-element subset have size $-2$. Similarly, $\binom{3}{5}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the special case $N=6, n=3$ and $(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(3,3,2)$. The valid triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ with $0\leq a_j\leq r_j,1\leq j\leq 3$ are:
\begin{align*}
&(1,3,2)\qquad\qquad(3,1,2)\\
&(2,2,2)\qquad\qquad(3,2,1)\\
&(2,3,1)\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{(3,3,0)}\\
\end{align*}
Note that we have $6$ valid triples since $a_j\geq 0$ and so $(3,3,0)$ is valid.

In the following we use the notation $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and define $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $p<0$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{S\subseteq [n]}&(-1)^{|S|}\binom{N+n-1-\sum_{i\in S}(r_i+1)}{n-1}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{S\subseteq [3]}(-1)^{|S|}\binom{8-\sum_{i\in S}(r_i+1)}{2}}\\
> &=(-1)^{|\emptyset|}\binom{8}{2}\\
> &\quad+(-1)^{|\{1\}|}\binom{8-4}{2}+(-1)^{|\{2\}|}\binom{8-4}{2}+(-1)^{|\{3\}|}\binom{8-3}{2}\\
> &\quad+(-1)^{|\{1,2\}|}\binom{8-(4+4)}{2}+(-1)^{|\{1,3\}|}\binom{8-(4+3)}{2}\\
> &\quad\qquad+(-1)^{|\{2,3\}|}\binom{8-(4+3)}{2}\\
> &\quad+(-1)^{|[3]|}\binom{8-(4+4+3)}{2}\\
> &=\binom{8}{2}-\binom{4}{2}-\binom{4}{2}-\binom{5}{2}+0+0+0-0\\
> &=28-6-6-10\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=6}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the list above.