# Number of possible quintuples $(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5)$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose there are $10$ students participating in a workshop that meets
> every day of a five-day work week. Each student must present a poster
> in exactly one of the days of the workshop, and every day of the
> workshop should have at least one poster presentation. If $n_k$ denotes
> the number of posters presented in day $k$ of the workshop, what is the
> number of possible quintuples $(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5)$?

We can reformulate this problem as those tuples $(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^5 n_i = 10$ and $n_i\geq 1$. Now I know that this integer program has $126$ solutions. Would this be the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Are you asking how to show that?

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1|85.7662#4268835), ignore the Inclusion-Exclusion theory and focus on the Stars and Bars theory.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I only want to confirm if the reformulation is correct

Comment: @user2661923 precisely how I solve it, but want to know if the reformulation is correct. That is, are the two problems the same or if I'm missing something

Comment: If you solved it the same way as that done in the linked answer, then yes, your approach was valid.  That is, the set of solutions to $~x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: ~x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}~$ bijects to the set of solutions to $~y_1 + \cdots + y_k = (n - k) ~: ~y_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Comment: Your reformulation is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you