# Drawing 6 chocolates from 15 chocolates with given constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Number of ways we can draw 6 chocolates drawn from 15 chocolates out of which 4 are blue, 5 are red and 6 are green if chocolates of the same colour are not distinguishable?

> what i did was to use the coefficient method $x^6$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2..+x^6)(1+x+x^2+x^3+..+x^5)(1+x+x^2..+x^4)$. This should give the answer but i considered if there was a better approach for this problem rather than coefficient calculations ? I was looking if it was possible to solve it using Principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Thats nice thanks

Comment: Actually i wanted just the opposite , i didnt want to use that polynomial coeffiecient method

Comment: Why exactly do you wish for another method? Are you finding the calculations in the current method hard? If it's calculations, there is a trick to speed it up for computing coefficients

Comment: Secondly, could you show your attempt in applying Inclusion /Exclusion? It would make your post more likely to get upvoted and also answered

Comment: This problem is pretty much a duplicate.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835#4268835).  If you have any questions about adjusting the linked answer to fit your Math problem, leave a comment, that includes the @user2661923 flag.

Comment: @Buraian You linked to the exact same posting that I did, except that you linked to the question, and I linked to my answer.  I am glad that you added a generating function answer to that question.  I wonder how much trouble it would be for you to generalize your answer, as I generalized mine, rather than making your generating function answer specific to this posting's question.