# Finding the number of combinations for any total number T given by a sum of n five sided dices with side values ranging from 2 to 6.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, combinations

#### The setting

I know how to calculate the number of combinations for any given sum and side of a dice but i wanted to caculate the number of combination for any given sum with a dice starting not a one but at two and still ending at six.

I visualized the problem as a set problem with a venn diagram.

I first computed the number of combination giving me the sum T using t six sided dices ( = the common formula).

Then i realized that any combinations including a one and giving me a sum T had to have an intermediary sum of T-1 with t-1 dices.
So I first computed the number of combinations giving me T with t dices and then I deduced the number of computations giving me T-1 with t-1 dices :

 
 
$$P(t,s,T)=( \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{T-t}{s}}\rfloor} (-1)^k * \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\frac{(T-s*k-1)!}{(T-s*k-n)!*(n-1)!}-?*\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{T-t}{s}}\rfloor} (-1)^k * \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\frac{(T-s*k-2)!}{(T-1-s*k-n)!*(n-1)!}) *(\frac{1}{s})^t$$

 
 
Where:
=number of rolls
=number of cards
=total value
?= what i need help to find

#### The problem

The difficulty arise when i have to multiply the number of combinations giving me T-1 with t-1 side to find the number of combinations they birthed with t dices.

I m really stuck and I'm now at the point where I have cut sheet of paper in tiny bits to visualize all of this and my desk is an absolute mess.

**Really a huge thanks for any help !!**

Comment: Duplicate problem already answered.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.0753#4268835).  One difficulty is that I am construing the $n$ dice to be distinguishable.  If that is not your intent, then the linked answer does not apply.

Comment: Re previous comment, you also have the trivial difference that the lower bound is $(2)$ for each die, rather than $(0)$.  However, that difference is easily adjusted for using the methods in the linked answer.

Comment: Another problem with my linked answer is that it does not use recursion, in any way.  From your posting, it seems as if you are looking for a recursion based approach.  For these types of problems, assuming that the dice are distinguishable, I have seen Stars and Bars theory used, or generating functions used.  I have never seen recursion used.