# Combination of elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have 3 subsets: A, B and C, each have 100 elements. How can I calculate how many combinations I can have of A B and C for a total of 100 elements in a new subset.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also to clarify the question...as it stands, I am not sure what you are asking.  Perhaps it would help to work it out explicitly for some number smaller than $100$.  Maybe $3$ is good enough to clarify the situation.

Comment: Must you have at least one each from $A,B,C,$ or is it permissible to have, say, $A=0, B=0, C=100$

Comment: I should clarify. One combinaiton would be 1 element A, 1 element B and 98 element C. Another combination would be 1 element A, 2 element B and 97 element C and so on.

Comment: @JR19 you should add your clarification to the question part , because the question and your actual purpose are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your clarification, it seems clear that You are asking for **combinations**, thus order doesn't matter, and that there must be at least $1$ each from $A,B,C$

This is easily solved by a version of  "stars and bars" which is explained  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504858/how-many-ways-can-we-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-strictly-positive-numbers/4504888#4504888) (you need not see the ADDED portion)

Using the formula $\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$,

the answer is  $\dbinom{100-1}{3-1} = \boxed{4851}$

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the question seems rather simple, so maybe a clarification on what you asked is needed, but for now: let's assume you don't care about order and there's no limits on how many elements from A, B or C you need to get every time, then we can consider a general total pool of $300$ elements. Since there are $\tbinom {n}{k}$ ways to choose an (unordered) subset of $k$ elements from a fixed set of $n$ elements, you're answer would be $\tbinom {300}{100}=4,158,251,463,258,564,744,783,383,526,326,405,580,280,466,005,743,648,708,663,033,658,000,000,000,000,000,000$
hope this helps

Edit1: the clarification made on the comments takes out the cases $0,0,100$ and $0,100,0$ and $100,0,0$. It is still not clear what happens when we reach $1,98,1$, if order is counted or not and if something like $2,2,96$ is possible...