# Dice sum of the points $12$

Tags: combinatorics

> $3$ dice are rolled. In how many of the possible $6^3$ outcomes is the
> sum of the points $12$?

*Attempt:* I would like to solve this problem using stars and bars. I arrived at the equation $x+y+z=12$. And to ensure that none of them have a value of zero, I feared $a=x+1$, $b=y+1$, and $c=z+1$. So we will have $a+b+c=9$. I thought of the following reasoning: "How many 3-digit numbers can be formed so that the sum of their digits equals 9?"

But I don't understand how to solve it, or if even reasoning would help to solve this problem by this method. The problem's answer is $25$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.1654#4268835).

Comment: Well, you can certainly just enumerate the examples. If the first die is $1,$ how many ways can the other dice add up to $11?$ Etc.

Comment: Stars and bars doesn't work well when there is an upper limit on the size of the numbers. Well, it can be made to work, using inclusion/exclusion and stars and bars. But inclusion/exclusion is more complicated.

Comment: In particular, your three digit number question can be solved with stars and bars, but not if you restrict the digits or $0,1,2,3,4,5.$

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion gives $\binom{9+2}{2}-3\binom{9+2-6}{2}=25.$