# Partial Fraction of $\frac{1-x^{11}}{(1-x)^4} $ for Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, partial-fractions

The original question involves using generating functions to solve for the number of integer solutions to the equation $c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4 = 20$ when $-3 \leq c_1, -3 \leq c_2, -5 \leq c_3 \leq 5, 0 \leq c_4$.

Using generating functions I was able to get it into the rational polynomial form:
$$f(x) = {\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}^3\left(\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}\right) = \frac{1-x^{11}}{{(1-x)}^4}$$

I was also able to determine that the sequence could be represented in two factors:
$${\left(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+\cdots\right)}^3\left(1+x^1+x^2+\cdots+x^{10}\right)$$

However, to find the coefficient on $x^{31}$ to solve the problem, I figured I would have to get the term $\frac{1-x^{11}}{{(1-x)}^4}$ into a more typical generating function summation form. Thus, I endeavored to find the partial fraction decomposition of the term, however, I can't seem to do it at all.

How would I find the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1-x^{11}}{{(1-x)}^4}$?
Or is there a better method in using ${(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+\ldots)}^3(1+x^1+x^2+\ldots+x^{10})$ in order to find the coefficient on $x^{31}$?

Thank you very much for your help, I've been trying this partial fraction for a while now and Wolfram alpha doesn't seem to be giving me an answer that is of much value.

Comment: You don't need to use partial fractions. Do you know the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^4}$? Use the binomial theorem with negative exponent. Then multiply the result by $x^{11}$ and subtract.

Comment: I was able to expand $\frac{1}{{(1-x)}^4}$. However, could you provide more clarity on what I am subtracting the multiplied result by?

Comment: You take the coefficients from $\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$ and $\frac{x^{11}}{(1-x)^4}$ and combine them.

Comment: **Moderately** *off-topic*.  Whatever *final computation* that you arrive at, via generating functions, may be **sanity-checked** by using the alternative method of attack that involves the interaction between Stars and Bars theory and Inclusion-Exclusion.  You will have to closely scrutinize the methods used in  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.3138#4268835) to apply the *sanity-checking*.

Comment: Re last comment, as an illustrative example, consider that the number of solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 = 5 ~: ~x_1, ~x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq -1}}$$ is the **same as** the number of solutions to $$y_1 + y_2 = (5 + 2) ~: ~y_1, ~y_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$  This conclusion is arrived at via the change of variables $$y_1 = x_1 + 1, ~y_2 = x_2 + 1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1-x^{11}}{(1-x)^4}&=(1-x^{11})\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}x^n-\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}x^{n+11}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}x^n-\sum_{n\ge11}\frac{(n-10)(n-9)(n-8)}{6}x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{6}\bigg((n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-(n-10)(n-9)(n-8)[n\ge11]\bigg)x^n,
\end{align}$$
where $[n\ge11]$ is the [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the
generalized binomial theorem
in the form

$
\dfrac1{(1-x)^s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1-x^a}{(1-x)^s}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
-x^a\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^{k+a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
-\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-a-1}{s-1}x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
+\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
-\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\binom{s+k-a-1}{s-1}x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
+\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\left(\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}-\binom{s+k-a-1}{s-1}\right)x^k
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
+\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\left(\dfrac{(s+k-1)!}{(s-1)!k!}-\dfrac{(s+k-a-1)!}{(s-1)!(k-a)!}\right)x^k
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}
\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
+\sum_{k=a}^{\infty}
\left(\dfrac{(s+k-1)!}{(s-1)!k!}-\dfrac{(s+k-a-1)!}{(s-1)!(k-a)!}\right)x^k
\\
\end{array}
$

You can do more manipulation if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{31}]\frac{1-x^{11}}{(1-x)^4}}
> &=\left([x^{31}]-[x^{20}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-4}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=\left([x^{31}]-[x^{20}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+3}{j}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{34}{31}-\binom{23}{20}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4\,213}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$ and make a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we select the coefficients accordingly.