# Find the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ such that $1 \leq x_i \leq n$ for each $x_i$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integers, inclusion-exclusion

This can be reformulated as finding the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such that $0 \leq x_i \leq n-1$ for each $x_i$.

My first instinct was to use generating functions and attempt to determine the coefficient attached to $x^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ in the expansion of $(1 + x + \cdots + x^{n-1})^n = \left(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right)^n$ but wasn’t sure how to proceed.

Alternatively, inclusion-exclusion seems like it could get really messy here, and I’m unsure if I’m overlooking something such as the parity of $n$ that’ll be an important factor in solving. Any input on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your specific Math problem is solved by the answer given to a more generic problem.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.2563#4268835).

Comment: Re previous comment, note that (for example), the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 = k,$ where $x_1,x_2$ are each required to be greater than $(0)$ is the same as the number of non-negative integer solutions to $y_1 + y_2 = (k-2).$  Note the change of variable $y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{1,2\}.$