# What is the most efficient/correct approach to this combinatorics question?

Tags: combinatorics

there are 3 different kinds of textbooks. We have 10 of each textbook. How many ways can we pick 10 textbooks from these 30? (Order of picking doesn't matter)

Additional question: What if we only had 9 of each kind of textbook?

I basically tried writing out every single combination and found that if there are 10 of textbook A, there's only 1 combination. If there are 9, there's 2 combinations.... all the way till theres 0 textbook A. So my final answer is 1+2+3...+11. is this correct and is there a better approach?

I'm quite unsure of my approach and answer because its a combinations question but i didnt use any C or P functions

Comment: Consider the number of solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10 ~: ~x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$  This is a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Re previous comment, the 2nd question posed is equivalent to adding an upper bound: $$x_1,x_2,x_3 \leq 9.$$  After completely digesting my previous comment, to attack the 2nd question, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.3498#4268835).