# How many 4-digit numbers have a digit sum equal to 21

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What I have so far is using inclusion/exclusion on $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21$$
with the restrictions that $x_i \leq 9$, I get:

$$C(24,3)-C(4,1)C(14,3)+C(4,2)C(4,3)$$

I know this is the incorrect solution, but I cannot figure out where I went wrong. If someone could tell me what I have missed or if I've gone in the wrong direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have correctly followed the algorithm in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.2789#4268835).

However, you overlooked that you must deduct all integer solutions to

$$0 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21 ~: ~0 \leq x_i \leq 9 ~: ~i \in \{2,3,4\}.$$

That is, you overlooked that you have to deduct all solutions where the leftmost digit is $0$.

---

An alternative approach would have been:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21$
- $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 $ each $~< 10.$
- $x_1 \geq 1.$

The above could then have been **bijected** to

$y_1 = x_1 - 1 ~: 0 \leq y_1 \leq 8.$

Then you have that $y_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20.$

Comment: Oh, because x_1 cant be 0, just to make sure how would the final solution look? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @freeantivirus Consider the editing that I just placed at the end of my answer.  Consider enumerating the number of solutions to $y_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20 ~: ~y_1 \leq 8.$  Let me know if you still have questions.