# What is the probability of rolling three dice and obtaining a sum between 5 to 10(inclusively)?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of rolling three dice and obtaining a sum between 5 to 10(inclusively)?

For two dice, it is easy to create a list containing the outcomes of each dice since there are only 36 cases. ({1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, ... , {6,5}, {6,6}).

But for three dice, there are $6^3$ cases. Therefore, how can I calculate the probability of the given question without writing down every possible combinations ?

Comment: Have you learnt "stars and bars" ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I have not.

Comment: Stars and bars, also known as sticks and stones, dots and dividers, etc. If not,  what topics have you learnt so far ?

Comment: Suppose the dice are blue, red, and green.  For each possible value on the blue die, in how many ways can the red and green die give you a sum in the correct range?

Comment: @trueblueanil Now I can understand the statement. I have learned the concept using '0' and '1', which is the same as stars and bars. I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @Woshi: Good for you ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer.**

Instead, this is a long-winded comment.

I am not allowed to answer because your posting has defects.

For an explanation of the defects, see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Most of the theory that you will need is contained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.2931#4268835).

There are two additional pieces of theory needed.

$\underline{\text{Additional Theory-1}}$

Consider the following problem:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \leq n.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

The easy way to handle this is to create the variable $a$ and change the problem to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k + a = n.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- Note that by the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \leq n,$ 
  $a$ is forced to (**also**) be a non-negative integer.

$\underline{\text{Additional Theory-2}}$

The standard method of handling a problem like

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_\geq {1}}.$

is via the change of variables: 
$y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}.$

This leads to

- $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = (n-k)$
- $y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_k \in \Bbb{Z_\geq {0}}.$

Clearly, there is a bijection between the set of solutions to the $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ problem and the set of solutions to the $y_1,y_2, \cdots, y_k$ problem.  Therefore, the two problems have the **same number of solutions.**

For what it's worth, suppose that you are given

- $~n,m \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: ~n < m.$
- $P$ equals the number of solutions to 
  $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \leq m.$ 
  $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.
- $Q$ equals the number of solutions to 
  $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \leq (n-1).$ 
  $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.

Then, the number of solutions where $n \leq ~\text{the sum} ~\leq m$ 
will be $P - Q.$

---

One additional point.  Your posting represents a Probability problem, where the answer can be expressed as

$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 6^3.$$

Since each of the $216$ rolls are equally likely, each Stars and Bars *solution* is just as likely to occur as any of the other $215$ possible rolls.  Therefore, the problem reduces to enumerating $N$.