# Counting problems with limit-combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I want to put n indistinguishable balls in 12 distinguishable boxes, we number the boxes from 1-12. How many ways are there to distribute the balls if boxes except 1-4 get at least 1 ball and boxes 1-4 get at least 2 balls?

I understand that we can use stars and bars method to get the ways to distribute n ball in 12 boxes, which would be $\binom{n+12-1}{12-1} = \binom{n+11}{11}$. But how should I approach the conditions when there should be at least 1 balls and 4 boxes should have at least 2 balls?

Comment: I suggest that you study [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.3336#4268835), by first skimming it, and paying particular attention to **Addendum-2**, at the end of the answer.  The answer was originally intended to deal with **upper bounds** on the variables.  I added Addendum-2 to **also** show how **lower bounds** on the variables should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

So you know how $16$ of your indistinguishable balls have to be distributed.  You care about the distribution of the "extras."

$y_1=x_1-2, \ldots, y_4=x_4-2, y_5=x_5-1, \ldots, y_{12}=x_{12}-1, m=n-16$.

Solve for $\underset{i=1}{\overset {12}{\sum}}y_i=m$ using stars-and-bars.  There are $\binom{n-16+11}{11}=\binom{n-5}{11}$ solutions.