# Find number of integral solutions equation

Tags: combinations

find number of non negative integral solutions of equation x+y+z+w=150 where,0<=x<=50,0<=y<=50,0<=z<=50,0<=w<=100

I tried to solve it using partition method ((n+r-1)C(r-1)) but didn't got the right answer.

Comment: What all did you do *specifically*?  What in your attempt had to do with the upperbounds of your values?  Are you familiar with inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.3384#4268835).

Comment: @JMoravitz For what it's worth, given your comment, I did hesitate before providing the link.  I (somewhat arbitrarily) decided that the problem is so complicated for a student new to the theory, that it is just too easy for the student to legitimately feel overwhelmed.