# Find The Number Of Solutions To The Following Equation

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Find the number of integer solutions to the equation:

$x(1) + x(2) + ··· + x(11) = 49 $

such that $0 \leqslant x(r) \leqslant 8$ for each $r= 1, 2,...,8$

I Used Principle Of Inclusion And Exclusion To get the following:

When any $1$ of the $x(r)$ are $ \geqslant 9$

When any $2$ of the $x(r)$ are $\geqslant 9$
...

Until we are at-

When any $6$ of the $x(r) \geqslant 9$

And After This We Can't Proceed because the RHS would become negative ,

So I Am not sure what to do next...

Edit: I Want the Solution From The Ball And Box Principle And P.I.E. Contrary as Mentioned Below In The Comments

Comment: *HINT* *Firstly*, you need to apply stars and bars, and *then* apply inclusion- exclusion, starting with $\displaystyle{\binom{49+11-1}{11-1}}\;$ thus $\displaystyle{\binom{59}{10} - \binom{11}1\binom{50}{10} +...}$

Comment: The generic form of your question has been asked over and over again, on MathSE.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1|60.9039#4268835)
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to 
attack this generic type of problem.

Comment: Re my last comment, I am therefore voting to close this question, as a duplicate.