# Stars and Bars with constraints on the variables.

Tags: combinatorics

How do I find the number of solutions in the equation $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 +\dots+a_k=2021$$ in terms of $k$ with $1\leq a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\leq9$? I know the first step is to introduce a new variable, say $b_i + 1 = a_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k$ so that it turns into $$b_1+b_2+b_3+\dots b_k=2021-k$$ with $0\leq b_1, b_2,\dots, b_k\leq8$, but how do I continue?

Comment: To complete the problem, just follow the model in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.3457#4268835).  I am voting to close, as a duplicate.

Comment: With respect to the linked answer, in particular, notice the Addendum (shortcuts), which discuss capitalizing on the fact that each variable has the same upper bound.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the only other approach is *generating functions*, which I am ignorant of.