# There are $\mathrm{400}$ identical seats to be distributed among $\mathrm{3}$ parties such that each party has at most $\mathrm{200}$ seats

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> There are $\mathrm{400}$ identical seats to be distributed among $\mathrm{3}$ parties such that each party has at most $\mathrm{200}$ seats. What is the number $\mathrm{L}$ of all the possibilities among the above?

There are $\mathrm{{399}\choose{2}}$ possibilities in total and I have to subtract $\mathrm{{198}\choose{2}}$ choices, where there is more than $\mathrm{200}$ seats assigned to one party. Is this answer correct?

Comment: Does it say that every party must have at least one seat ?

Comment: Are "seats" distinguishable people? So this is equivalent to saying "There are 400 people to be assigned to three rooms such that...."? Or am I overthinking and you literally mean 400 identical chairs?

Comment: Also, think more carefully about the inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @AlgTop1854: "...identical seats..." is wtitten.

Comment: $~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 400~$ and $~x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{0 \leq x_i \leq 200}},~$ with possible additional constraint that each $~x_i \geq 1.~$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1|60.9039#4268835)
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to 
attack this generic type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assumed that every party gets at least one seat, which has not been specified in the problem statement.

Also, you have forgotten that *any* of the three parties must not get more than $200$ seats.

If I go by the wording of the question, the answer using stars and bars (written in the full form) gives

$\dbinom{400+3-1} 2 - 3*\dbinom{(400-201)+3-1}2 = 20,301$

which tallies with David G. Stork's answer

But it is quite possible (though not mentioned) that every party is supposed to get at least $1$ seat.

Can you now work out the answer for *this* problem (which you were attempting) correctly ? Will it be the same or different ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{200} \sum\limits_{j=200-i}^{200} 1 \right) = 20,301$$

Where $i$ is the number of seats for the first group, $j$ the number in the second group (and the rest are in the third group).

It is unclear whether the groups are considered distinct.

Comment: May I ask what's the idea behind this formula?